# Converting a Text File to a String in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, input

I am new to python and am trying to find the largest word in the alice_in_worderland.txt. I think I have a good system set up ("See Below"), but my output is returning a "word" with dashes connecting multiple words. Is there someway to remove the dashes in the input of the file? For the text file visit [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/resources/ch10/alice_in_wonderland.txt)

sample from text file:

> That's very important,' the King said, turning to the jury. They were
>   just beginning to write this down on their slates, when the White
>   Rabbit interrupted:  UNimportant, your Majesty means, of course,' he
>   said in a very respectful tone, but frowning and making faces at him
>   as he spoke. " UNimportant, of course, I meant,' the King hastily
>   said, and went on to himself in an undertone, important--unimportant--
>   unimportant--important--' as if he were trying which word sounded
>   best."

code:

---

```
    #String input
    with open("alice_in_wonderland.txt", "r") as myfile:
        string=myfile.read().replace('\n','')
    #initialize list
    my_list = []
    #Split words into list
    for word in string.split(' '):
        my_list.append(word)
    #initialize list
    uniqueWords = []
    #Fill in new list with unique words to shorten final printout
    for i in my_list:
        if not i in uniqueWords:
            uniqueWords.append(i)
    #Legnth of longest word
    count = 0
    #Longest word place holder
    longest = []
    for word in uniqueWords:
        if len(word)>count:
            longest = word
            count = len(longest)
        print longest
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input (not everyone wants to follow a link to get your data) and output that's required? Describe how it differs from what you've got now etc...

Comment: `That's very important,' the King said, turning to the jury.
They were just beginning to write this down on their slates, when
the White Rabbit interrupted:  `UNimportant, your Majesty means,
of course,' he said in a very respectful tone, but frowning and
making faces at him as he spoke.

 " `UNimportant, of course, I meant,' the King hastily said, and
went on to himself in an undertone, `important--unimportant--
unimportant--important--' as if he were trying which word
sounded best."

Comment: This is a small subset with the unusual quote. I don't know if I can count the dashed phase as the longest word though, so any thoughts on how to remove them from the input? Maybe something like .replace('\n','\-','')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import nltk # pip install nltk
>>> nltk.download('gutenberg')
>>> words = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('carroll-alice.txt')
>>> max(words, key=len) # find the longest word
'disappointment'
```

Comment: Seems we get the same answer then

Comment: +1 from me for serious usage of word usage - NLTK is the way to go

Comment: thumbs up! I didn't know about nltk

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `re` and `mmap`:

```
import re
import mmap

with open('your alice in wonderland file') as fin:
    mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    words = re.finditer('\w+', mf)
    print max((word.group() for word in words), key=len)

# disappointment
```

Far more efficient than loading the file to physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace` to replace the dashes with spaces (or whatever you want). To do this, simply add another call to replace after the first call on line 3:

```
string=myfile.read().replace('\n','').replace('-', ' ')
```